# Typescript - how to omit properties so a subset can be transferred with spread?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Versions: Typescript 3 and React 16.

I want to pass in custom properties and allow override of all standard HTML properties on my component.

Component usage:

```
<ExamplePropTransfer specialProp={"test"} style={{color:'blue'}}/>
```

ExamplePropTransfer:

```
import * as React from "react"
import {HTMLProps, PureComponent} from "react";

export interface ExampleProps{
  specialProp: string;
  // and possibly many more
}

export class ExamplePropTransfer
extends PureComponent<ExampleProps & HTMLProps<HTMLSpanElement>> {

  render(){
    console.log("specialProp: " + this.props.specialProp);

    // (A)
    // warning.js:33 Warning: React does not recognize the
    // `specialProp` prop on a DOM element.
    // return <span {...(this.props as HTMLProps<HTMLSpanElement>)}>
    //   Example Content
    // </span>

    // (B)
    let {specialProp, ...htmlProps} = this.props;
    return <span {...htmlProps}>Example Content</span>
  }
}
```

The only way I've been able to make this work is (B) in the above example code.

But it's error prone because I'm repeating myself.  Whenever I add/remove members in `ExampleProps` I have to go maintain the destructuring statement.

The whole destructuring statement is superfluous. I don't *need* references to the individual properties - I'm only doing it to peel my custom properties off so they don't get passed as `span` properties.

I tried doing (A), but that still passes `specialProps` to the `span` and causes `React` to log the warning show above.

I'm trying to tell Typescript to "transfer all the properties from this.props except the ones defined on `ExampleProps`" *without having to list them explicitly*?

Comment: what about creating one special prop that aggregates all additional props? In this way you will have to strip only one prop ever.

Comment: and why do you pass props to a component that you don't need inside of a component?

Comment: you could also go in another direction and pass to an html element only props that it will possibly might need (i.e. `style`, `className` and `id`)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use metadata reflection, interfaces don't exist at runtime, so there's no way to "transfer all the properties except those defined on `ExampleProps`" at runtime.  I'm not familiar with metadata reflection to give an example, but here's an alternative approach that gives you both an `ExampleProps` type and the ability to remove the props at runtime without repeating yourself:

```
import * as React from "react"
import {HTMLProps, PureComponent} from "react";
import _ from "underscore";

type Placeholder<T> = {placeholder: T};
function p<T>() { return {} as Placeholder<T>; }
const examplePropsSpec = {
  specialProp: p<string>()
};

export type ExampleProps = {
  [K in keyof typeof examplePropsSpec]:
  (typeof examplePropsSpec)[K] extends Placeholder<infer T> ? T : never;
};

export class ExamplePropTransfer
extends PureComponent<ExampleProps & HTMLProps<HTMLSpanElement>> {

  render(){
    console.log("specialProp: " + this.props.specialProp);

    let htmlProps = _.omit(this.props, Object.keys(examplePropsSpec));
    return <span {...htmlProps}>Example Content</span>
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, pretty clever. I've simplified your solution a bit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Matt's answer is pretty fantastic but I think it can be simplified a little bit (no Placeholder type needed):

```
function p<T>() { return null as any as T; }
const examplePropsSpec = {
  specialProp: p<string>(),
};

export type ExampleProps = {
  [K in keyof typeof examplePropsSpec]: (typeof examplePropsSpec)[K];
};


let k: ExampleProps = {
  specialProp: "k"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want a TypeScript interface to exist at runtime without using reflection, we can create it, using an object literal to hold of the members in the interface. It's fragile but the compiler will tell us if the interface has changed so that we can adjust the interface object.

Then, we can filter an object to keep only its properties which keys are in the interface.

POC:

```js
// @types/react/index.d.ts

interface HTMLProps<T> {
    accept?: string;
    acceptCharset?: string;
    action?: string;
    // ... see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/10a19353e01f9cd275d4efda9be386c3dc7d6115/types/react/index.d.ts
}

// Our code

type Required<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P];
}

const allHTMLProps: Required<HTMLProps<any>> = {
    accept: '',
    acceptCharset: '',
    action: ''
    // ...
};

const allHTMLPropsKeys = Object.keys(allHTMLProps);

function filterHTMLProps<P, O>(o: O & HTMLProps<T>) {
    const result: HTMLProps<T> = {};
    Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
        if (allHTMLPropsKeys.indexOf(k) >= 0) {
            result[k] = o[k];
        }
    });
    return result;
}

const source = { accept: 'a', ko: 1 };
console.log(filterHTMLProps(source)); // { accept: 'a' }
```